# Simplify/Expand equation so that right side equals 0

Tags: syntax

Given an equation like
$$x^2 + (x + 82)^2 = (x + 100)^2,$$
how do I type to make this into
$$x^2-36x-3276=0\; ?\tag{1}$$
This *almost* does it

```
x^2 + (x + 82)^2 == (x + 100)^2 // Simplify // Expand
```

but not completely. Naturally,

```
x^2 + (x + 82)^2 - (x + 100)^2 // Simplify // Expand
```

partially solves it, but can Mathematica construct the equation (1)? TIA.

Comment: `Collect[x^2 + (x + 82)^2 - (x + 100)^2 == 0, x]`

Comment: There's a  typo in your (1) equation. The $x$ term is missing an $x$. It's just 36.

Comment: Thanks. I added the 'x'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f = Expand @* SubtractSides;

f[x^2 + (x + 82)^2 == (x + 100)^2]
```

> ```
> -3276 - 36 x + x^2 == 0
> ```

```
TraditionalForm @ %
```

[image]

```
PolynomialForm[%%, TraditionalOrder -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Oooh, I wish I had known about `SubtractSides` before now! Very cool. (`ApplySides[Expand,x^2 + (x + 82)^2 == (x + 100)^2]//SubtractSides` also works)

Answer (score 3):

This is a great example to use the [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html)option to `Simplify` and the undocumented `PolynomialForm`.

```
expr = x^2 + (x + 82)^2 == (x + 100)^2; 
Simplify[expr, ComplexityFunction -> (If[MatchQ[#1, _ == 0], 0, 1] &)]
PolynomialForm[%, TraditionalOrder -> True]
```

> -3276 - 36 x + x^2 == 0

> x^2 - 36 x - 3276 == 0

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this, but I'd typically do it this way

```
expr = x^2 + (x + 82)^2 == (x + 100)^2;

# - Last[expr] & /@ %
(* x^2 + (82 + x)^2 - (100 + x)^2 == 0 *)
```